# Futures trading not possible: APIError(code=-4164): Order's notional must be no smaller than 5.0

Tags: python, api, bots, bitcoin, binance

I'm trying to create a new futures order with a little money in order to test my bot but gives me errors:

```
order=client.futures_create_order(symbol=sym,side=f'{signal}',type='MARKET',positionSide= "LONG",quantity=str(coinQuantity),leverage=10)
```

error=binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-4164): Order's notional must be no smaller than 5.0 (unless you choose reduce only)
I really don't know what notional means in here and what is restricting me,I did this change:

```
order=client.futures_create_order(symbol=sym,side=f'{signal}',type='MARKET',positionSide= "LONG",quantity=str(coinQuantity),leverage=10,reduceOnly='true')
```

but also this time it gives me this error:binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1106): Parameter 'reduceOnly' sent when not required.
coinQuantity is 0.001 and symbol is 'ETHUSDT'.
python 3.7.9

Answer (score 4):

The new update from binance will not let trades in futures to be made using api less than 5 dollars(and that was what notional was meant!) so I needed to make my trade a bit bigger than 5 dollars like 5.01. and positionSide(and reduceOnly) parameter was absolutely unnecessary ,since it is only needed for hedge mood.
The new [update](https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/1d762daf60dd417f9d8a05d44b06a25c).

Comment: yap basically we need to increase order_amount if its less than minimum value to place the order it gives following error

Answer (score 0):

The quantity parameter  is not calculated in USDT, you need to set quantity of asset you are trading with. For example, let's say that 1 BAT = 0.423 USDT at the moment, and you want to trade with 5 USDT, so:

`5 / 0,423 = 11.82`

That means that your quantity parameter should be at least 11.82.