# How to use Binance Helper to round quantity and price properly?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

It's been a few days since I've been trying to wrap up my head around this problem of what amount of decimals to round the **quantity** and **price** to.

The following errors are the errors that happen once you satisfy one error, then the other is not satisfied:

```
    APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.
    APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER
    APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: MIN_NOTIONAL
    APIError(code=-4164): Order's notional must be no smaller than 5.0 (unless you choose reduce only)
```

and while using different symbols (**BTCUSDT, XRPUSDT, 1000SHIBUSDT etc.**) with different decimals, manually going through this is a big headache, so I need to know how to automatically fix this with **Binance Helper**, see here: https://sammchardy.github.io/binance-order-filters/

I went through the above guide, and also searched many **Stack Overflow** questions, but couldn't understand still - I'm confused... :(

For example, I want to buy **BTCUSDT**, and I have `quantity = 0.00001` - I get an error:
`APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.`

Example 2: I want to buy **XRPUSDT** - `quantity = 24` - I get an error: `APIError(code=-4164): Order's notional must be no smaller than 5.0 (unless you choose reduce only)`

How do I get quantity and price precision for a specific symbol automatically using a function?

Let me know if I need to provide more details, thanks

Comment: Is this helpful? --> <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68153864/futures-trading-not-possible-apierrorcode-4164-orders-notional-must-be-no>. Or this? --> <https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/947>

Comment: Yeah, I understand that part now, thanks. What about rounding the quantity and price? Also, can I have your Discord, if you're okay with that?