# Get Futures order status, qty, side Binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to get the status of order, quantity, and side; however, I get following error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Data:

```
[{'orderId': 123xxx, 'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'status': 'NEW', 'clientOrderId': 'xxx', 'price': '32000', 'avgPrice': '0', 'origQty': '0.001', 'executedQty': '0', 'cumQuote': '0', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'reduceOnly': False, 'closePosition': False, 'side': 'BUY', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'stopPrice': '0', 'workingType': 'CONTRACT_PRICE', 'priceProtect': False, 'origType': 'LIMIT', 'time': xxx, 'updateTime': xxx}, {'orderId': 123xxx, 'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'status': 'NEW', 'clientOrderId': 'xxx', 'price': '32000', 'avgPrice': '0', 'origQty': '0.001', 'executedQty': '0', 'cumQuote': '0', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'reduceOnly': False, 'closePosition': False, 'side': 'BUY', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'stopPrice': '0', 'workingType': 'CONTRACT_PRICE', 'priceProtect': False, 'origType': 'LIMIT', 'time': xxx, 'updateTime': xxx}]
```

Code:

```
get_open_order = client.futures_get_open_orders(symbol=config.SYMBOL, orderID=123xxx)

get_status = get_open_order['status']
get_qty = get_open_order['origQty']
get_side = get_open_order['side']

print(f"STATUS: {get_status} | QUANTITY: {get_qty} | SIDE: {get_side}")
```

What's the mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `get_open_order` is a `list` with two `dict` items, each an order.

This is how you can access the orders within the `list` (which I have renamed `get_open_orders` to indicate that it contains multiple orders, not just one).

```
        #get_open_order = client.futures_get_open_orders(symbol=config.SYMBOL, orderID=123xxx)
        get_open_orders = [
            {'orderId': 123001, 'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'status': 'NEW', 'clientOrderId': 'xxx', 'price': '32000', 'avgPrice': '0', 'origQty': '0.001', 'executedQty': '0', 'cumQuote': '0', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'reduceOnly': False, 'closePosition': False, 'side': 'BUY', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'stopPrice': '0', 'workingType': 'CONTRACT_PRICE', 'priceProtect': False, 'origType': 'LIMIT', 'time': 777, 'updateTime': 777}, 
            {'orderId': 123002, 'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'status': 'NEW', 'clientOrderId': 'xxx', 'price': '32000', 'avgPrice': '0', 'origQty': '0.001', 'executedQty': '0', 'cumQuote': '0', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'reduceOnly': False, 'closePosition': False, 'side': 'BUY', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'stopPrice': '0', 'workingType': 'CONTRACT_PRICE', 'priceProtect': False, 'origType': 'LIMIT', 'time': 777, 'updateTime': 777}
        ]        
        
        for get_open_order in get_open_orders:
            get_status = get_open_order['status']
            get_qty = get_open_order['origQty']
            get_side = get_open_order['side']

            print(f"STATUS: {get_status} | QUANTITY: {get_qty} | SIDE: {get_side}")
```

The output is:

```
STATUS: NEW | QUANTITY: 0.001 | SIDE: BUY
STATUS: NEW | QUANTITY: 0.001 | SIDE: BUY
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you be kind enough to also check my other unanswered question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198863/how-to-use-binance-helper-to-round-quantity-and-price-properly